# User Credentials in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm a newbie with ASP.NET **Web API** and I heard so much about it that, it's the new industry standard and all, I've decided to build a regular hotel management system with it. I created some models and generated controls and created database using code-first migration. It all was tough at the beginning but now I've got hold of the essence. It's Awesome.

Now I'm stuck at the user management level. According to Web API spec there are options to manage access to resources like basic, Forms, integrated Win and OAuth. And also something about 2-legged and 3-legged which I understand are all authentication options which involves another data source or app (may be not the right terms) that will handle the authentication on behalf of the Web API I build.

Since my application is simple (for now), I was thinking is it possible to allow the Web API to include the necessary authentication, for example authenticating (user) and authorizing (role) before giving access to the data, thus seliminating the "LEGGED" dependance but at the same time it is open to allow 2-LEGGED and 3-LEGGED implementation in the future if I wish to.

From what I've seen and read the Web API is not ideal for a system like what I'm developing. Hope I'm wrong coz I find it awesome in terms of a service that can be consumed by other systems.

In my mind the big picture for the system is to allow customersI and third parties to access

- hotel information via web and smart phones to check room availability and book rooms
- restaurant information ...
- hotel events, spa..etc

Please advice, to achieve this, how do I go about implementing authentication and authorization?

Comment: hello ppl, please tell me if i'm asking the wrong questions.